# AngularJS: Alerts not showing up

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am using [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/alerts) for Bootstrap components and trying to show up the alerts

Here is the plunker - http://plunker.co/edit/DFBs3hTobHDs36QdqPte?p=preview

It does not shows up the alerts, what is that I am missing?

Comment: **Much Better Way - using Timeouts**

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824157/angularjs-directive-how-do-i-hide-the-alert-using-timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way I found is using directives

The plunker can be found here - http://plnkr.co/edit/uqSB1gIz6XEmJfC8zHNb?p=preview

I am still trying to figure out how to add timeout and hide the message

Answer (score 0):

I have got the plunker working

http://plunker.co/edit/DFBs3hTobHDs36QdqPte?p=preview

The codebase says it can accept `timeout` parameter, but I do not know yet how to use it

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/directives/alert.js#L5

Comment: That is not a `timeout` parameter, it is a dependency on `$timeout`, which is provided by [AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout).

Comment: I see, do you see any way I can use timeouts?