# AngularJS: Alerts don't show up when multiple messages change ngModel for message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

- I have a notification service which works well for when page is loaded and Controller is loaded
- But when I have different buttons calling different functions, they change message, but alerts don't show up

Here is a plunker for that - http://plnkr.co/edit/YioiJXNkaET6T2mexjCq?p=preview

What is that I need to do to update it whenever `$scope.message` changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `$watch` the model and show the alert when it changes.
http://plnkr.co/edit/fJuP9LWH4MNVV1cQs3ED?p=preview

In linker function of your directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
    element.show();
    $timeout(function(){
      //element.empty();
      element.hide();
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that ( w.r.t the plnkr implementation), you may not get the alert again if needed. How do we get that back?